# How to run video on streamlit?

Tags: video, gif, streamlit

I am trying to use a video in streamlit that is only 20 sec long but I would like to extended it so it will repeat itself automatically and run there without stoppage(so I do not have to tap the play button every 20 sec:). I would also like to have the video running automatically once my app is running on streamlit.

Could anyone help me how to do it?

[image: The video I want to loop]

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the video file into a GIF, upload it to giphy.com, click "share", then "copy GIF link" and finally add it into streamlit with:

```py
st.markdown("![Alt Text](https://media.giphy.com/media/og52So0BUmZVe/giphy.gif)")
```

[image: A gif running in the background]